# Can i add a swift view controller in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I work on an objective c project. I am new to integrating objective c and swift.

I have read documents on how to use Swift classes methods from another objective c class and it is working but how do i proceed if i want to create a new view?

I use storyboards and .xib files in my project.
What is the right way to proceed on the integration including the View controller?

Do i have to create a new view controller in my existing storyboard or a .xib and then connect the view controller class that i create in swift?

Do i have to create a new swift view and then use my swift view controller class?

Please any help appreciated.

Comment: There is no functional difference between a controller in Objective-C or in Swift.

Comment: So i can create a seperate UIViewController in swift somehow? And then call this UIVIewcontroller from objective c to open the new swift view?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a UIViewController and use it on Objective c file you should:

1. Create a new UIViewController on a swift file inside your project.
2. Add the **@objc** annotation to the UIViewController like this:

   @objc class FamilyTimeBlockViewController: UIViewController { }
3. Create a UIViewController in the storyboard or in a new xib file (doesn't matter)
4. Assign your UIViewController class to the view (from step 3)
5. Call

   YourNewViewController * vc = [[YourNewViewController alloc]
   initWithNibName: @"YourViewName" bundle:nil];

in an objective c file wherever you need.

Where "YourNewViewController" is the name of the UIViewController class and YourViewName is the name of the view.

Comment: managed to do it but i get an error for an iboutlet uilabel i added in the viewcontroller in my storyboard. This error shows only when the uilabel is connected to the iboutlet in the swift class. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fd8acf98370> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key helloFromSwiftLabel.

Comment: Try to use separate .xib file for this and not a storyboard